# Is it possible that "Server-side fan-out" can process with Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Recently Cloud Functions has released on Firebase.

I'm developing social network service via Firebase and using "Fan-out" process for data consistency as explained on [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html).

Since "Client-side fan-out" is a bit inefficient for large data. Can we resolve this on Server-side with Cloud Functions?

If possible, can you guys give me a workaround to do this. Or if there is sample code with it please reference me.

For examples, if new data is inserted on `posts` node, how can we Fan-out this data on `timeline` node for each following user?

Thank you.

```
{
    "posts": {
        "-K-zOrtjiCGe7tgRk8DG": {
            "text": "I love emojis!",
            "uid": "user1"
        }
    },
    "timeline": {
        "user2": {
            "-K-zOrtjiCGe7tgRk8DG": {
                "text": "I love emojis!",
                "uid": "user1"
            }
        },
        "user3": {
            "-K-zOrtjiCGe7tgRk8DG": {
                "text": "I love emojis!",
                "uid": "user1"
            }
        }
    },
    "followers": {
        "user1": {
            "user2": true,
            "user3": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely write a [database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) with Cloud Functions for Firebase to do this.  The trigger function can run whenever something under /posts changes, get a hold of the new data, and write it to the other places in the database where it should be duplicated.  This removes the responsibility of all your clients to do the same work, and allows you to tighten up your security rules on the duplicated data.

Comment: Thank you. I also expect an article about "Server-side fan-out" on Firebase blog =)